# Modify variable in Z3 python

Tags: python, z3

I am writing some kind of application that simulate some rule. I find that fixedpoint of Z3py my be help. My app outline can be as follow:
(fp = Fixedpoint())

1. Declare some integer variables e.g: a, b, c = Ints('a b c') and register to fixedpoint - fp.(a, b, c)
2. Follow the property of some variables (the fact), increase or decrease some other variables. e.g:
   if (a>0 and b>0) then c=c+1
3. Query if a target variable satisfy some condition, e.g. query(target>0)

I do not know how to use the rule to specify 2. Could someone tell me is this possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I took the example you outlined and created an example:

- http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/kD1P

I hope this helps.

Z3 prints UNSAT because the query is not reachable. 
It then displays an invariant that certifies that 
the query is not reachable.

In more detail

To declare a property with three arguments do:

```
P = Function('P', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort(), BoolSort())
```

To register it for the fixedpoint engine:

```
fp.register_relation(P)
```

Add whatever rules you have in mind:

```
fp.rule(P(-1,1,-10))
fp.rule(P(a,b,c+1), [a > 0, b > 0, P(a,b,c)])
fp.rule(P(a+1,b,c-1), [a <= 0, b < 0, P(a,b,c)])
```

The first rule says something about what properties hold initially.
The second rule says that c can be incremented if a > 0, b > 0.

Finally ask if some property is reachable:

```
print fp.query(P(a,b,c),c > 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you, this does help me, however, the way Function is defined I still do not get that. Is that Function is just the way that tell the fixedpoint that its arguments are related to each other?